# SKSpriteNode has wrong positioning on x and y axis

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have declared a `SKSpriteNode`, with a pillar image. The image is 3000 x 50 and I have declared it like this:

```
var pairs = SKNode()

let pillar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pillar")
pillar.setScale(0.5)
pillar.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: pillar.size)
pillar.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
pillar.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
pillar.zPosition = 1

pairs.zPosition = 1
pairs.addChild(pillar)
```

When I set the position for my pillar I do this:

```
bottomWall.position = CGPoint(x: Int(self.frame.width) + 100, y: 0)
```

I have set y to 0, but the pillar image starts approximately  at the middle of the screen on the y-axis and for the x-axis this `Int(self.frame.width) + 100` positions the pillar 100px from the middle.

### So my question is:

Why is the behaviour and how can I make it so that `y: 0` starts a t `y: 0` and `x: 0` starts at `x: 0`?

Answer (score 0):

by default your SKScene has an anchorPoint of 0.5, 0.5. this that the default position for objects are in the center of the scene.

If you want objects to be placed starting in the lower left corner you need to set you scene anchorPoint to zero. set this inside the `func didMove(to view: SKView)`

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

or

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `position` of an object is regarding the center of the object.
In order for the `x` and `y` to represent the bottom left corner of the `bottomWall` you should set

`bottomWall.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0,y:0)`

before the line you position the `bottomWall`

This will use the bottom left corner of your object as `x` and `y` relatively to the screen.